# How do I loop through an NSSet of Core Data

Tags: core-data, swift2

I have a User entity and a Hobby entity and a relationhip of to-many where one User can have many Hobbies. I am adding the user to a hobby like this, `@IBAction func addHobby(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var newHobby = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Hobby", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Hobby
    newHobby.name = addHobbyTextField.text
    newHobby.user = curUser

    do{

        try context.save()
    } catch{

        print("There was a problem \(error)")
    }

}`
```

but I am trying to figure out how to loop through the User entity object to see what hobbies a certain user has. I am using this currently but its not working,

```
@IBAction func printUser(sender: AnyObject) {

    print(curUser!.hobby! as NSSet)

}
```

I get this in the console:

```
Relationship 'hobby' fault on managed object (0x7fef13674e10) <Core_Data_Demo.Users: 0x7fef13674e10> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://5E62A797-4124-4816-8AC0-32C5E723F830/Users/p1> ; data: {
hobby = "<relationship fault: 0x7fef134515c0 'hobby'>";
password = test;
username = free;
```

})

Any help would be awesome, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship will be a fault until you access it.  That is what you are seeing in your print.  You need to walk the relationship to see what is in it:

```
for item in curUser.hobby {
    print(item)
}
```

That will cause the relationship to be accessed which will realize the relationship and give you a set of objects to walk.

Note that even with that each hobby will be a fault so you may want to touch a property on the hobby instead of printing the entire object:

```
for item in curUser.hobby {
    print(item.name)
}
```

As an example.

I would suggest reading up on [faulting in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html)

Comment: That worked thank you! I will read up because its kind of confusing to me.